# persistent homology: how sensitive is the persistent homology of a dataset to reorderings of the elements in vector.

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex, topological-data-analysis

I have been looking at some of the applications of topological data analysis and persistent homology lately. I had a question about how sensitive persistent homology was to reordering of the data or points over which the homology is computed.

So say I am look at some point cloud of observations $x_i, i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Each observation is a vector, representing different features or measurements from the observation.

$$
 x_i =  \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{i,1} \\
           x_{i,2} \\
           x_{i,3} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{i,m}
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now if I compute the persistent homology of the set of points, I will obtain a barcode or persistence diagram, and the world is good.

**BUT, here is my question. If I were to reorder the elements in the each vector, would this change the barcode?** For example if I just did a simple reordering like

$$
 \hat{x_i} =  \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{i,3} \\
           x_{i,2} \\
           x_{i,1} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{i,m}
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here I just rearranged some of the elements of the original vector $x_i$ to produce $\hat{x_i}$. If I did this same reordering to all of the other observations in the dataset, would this change the barcode or persistent homology in any way?

It seems like most homology calculations are based upon some norm, and so reordering would not necessarily affect that norm. But I am not enough of an algebraic topologist to know whether there are other theoretical questions that can affect the stability of the persistent homology.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of TDA. To my knowledge/understanding,  no, it shouldn't matter.   TDA measures how long various "holes" of different dimensions last as you move the parameter.   All permuting the dimensions would do would be to rotate the shapes involved, and rotations preserve the topological structures.

Comment: thanks so much. Yes, this makes sense. I was trying to look in the TDA literature, but the algebraic topology language and notation are still rather foreign for applied math folks. I was trying to think of a formal way to justify this, but what you said makes sense. I am basically just multiplying each vector by some permutation matrix--something I might do in Gaussian elimination with row exchanges.

Comment: I also agree with the above answer --- it won't matter. There are several different ways to build an increasing sequence of spaces on top of a point cloud in order to compute persistent homology (the most common ways are Vietoris-Rips complexes, or Cech complexes, or alpha complexes). In all of these that I know about, including not only the aforementioned popular ones but also any others, the ordering of the points does not affect the resulting increasing sequence of spaces! Hence the ordering of points also does not affect the resulting persistent homology.